# Refreshing Gmail UI via Gmail Add on

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm currently trying to build a Gmail Add on that helps generate email drafts via an llm for a user.

The issue that I'm running into is when trying to generate a draft for a message in a thread that has a preexisting draft. When I generate the second draft for the same message, I need to refresh the entire page before seeing the compose UI updated with the latest draft text.

Does anyone know if there's a way for me to be able to have the Gmail UI update without refreshing the entire page? What also might help is if the compose UI for the most recently created draft was displayed in a pop-up view window, but I couldn't really find any good documentation on being able to show the compose UI in a pop up (I am using .setGmailDraft) at the moment.

`return CardService.newComposeActionResponseBuilder() .setGmailDraft(draft).build();`

I tried using the .update method in GmailDraft but that only seems to be updating the draft state in Gmail's backend - the frontend is not aware of this change. It seems that I have to refresh the page for the frontend to know about the latest draft that was created.

Comment: As far as I know, you must refresh the entire page.